# Escaping hex sequences

Tags: c, hex, ascii

I'm try to create a hex escape sequence that will correspond to an actual hex value.

I've never really used a hex escape sequence, but as a first attempt I wanted to create the hex value: 0x12345678

Would I need the following?:

```
hex_value = "\x30\x78\x31\x32\x33\x34\x35\x36\x37\x38"
```

I found the hex values for the characters here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: `"\x78\x56\x34\x12"` (if little endian).

Comment: If it is in a string, do I need to have "0x" before the rest of the values in order for it to be processed as a hex value?

Comment: `0x` is the prefix for the compiler to recognize a sequence of hexadecimal number. It is not related here, since you are playing around with bytes, when put together creates an representation of a number.

Comment: If you're trying to typecast the memory as an integer greater than 8-bits, be aware of endianness issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to create strings of hex values.

```
char a[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0 };
char *aa = "\x12\x34\x56\x78";
```

Note that you use `0x` on a bare number and `\x` in a string.

Now, the first 4 bytes of the `a` array may or may not correspond to the 32bit integer value 0x12345678. It will do so on a "big-endian" system, but not on a "little-endian" system (where the bytes would be reversed). Because there are different conventions for how a multi-byte integer is arranged in memory. There are even bizarre systems where the two words are ordered using one convention and the two bytes in the words are ordered using the other (I forget which system, and I forget what the combination was).

This program will output the appropriate hex-escape sequence for a given integer if compiled and run on the target system.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i = 0x12345678;
    unsigned char *p = (void *)&i;
    printf("\\x%2x\\x%2x\\x%2x\\x%2x\n", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be an actual string, don't forget a terminating 0 in the first instance!